# importing data to sql server database from json

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, json, import

I am attempting to import data into a SQL Server 2012 database from a large json file using Python 2.7. Everything in the below code executes and returns no error, however when I go into Sql Server Management Studio and query the table, it returns zero rows. Why is this?

```
import json, pyodbc

#import data
path = 'phys2211-001_clickstream_export'
records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path)]

#connect to database, create db cursor
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=fall_2013_blended;Trusted_Connection=Yes')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

#insert data into db
for record in records:
    cursor.execute("insert into clickstream_json(json_event) values (?)",json.dumps(record))
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have autocommit setup. Therefore it ran through everything then committed nothing to the database. It was similar to this question:
[Issue creating table in MS SQL Database with Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683287/issue-creating-table-in-ms-sql-database-with-python-script)